# check if I have touch my bitmap image or not android canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas, bitmapimage

I'm trying to make a canvas and add some bitmap images to it and want to know which bitmap image user touch, so how can I do that

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you show us what you already have?

Answer (score 1):

set onTouch listener to your view, get touch coordinates and get corresponding bitmap according to coordinates that were drawn on canvas.

Answer (score 1):

check where user has touched

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        int _x = (int) event.getX();
        int _y = (int) event.getY();

        System.out.println("Value of _x  "   _x);
        System.out.println("Value of _y  "  _y);
```

and the match to the axis of the click to the axis of the image like this

```
if(( y>=360 && y<=396  &&_y>=430 &&  _y<=475  &&  _x>15 &&  _x<100 ))
        {  
           System.out.println("SUCCESS");

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could insert the bitmaps in separate `ImageView`s and set onTouch listeners for them. You usually don't need to subclass the standard components, and when you don't, you can use many of the system services at your convenience.